# Displaying last 'N' posts by friends & me

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the latest 'N' posts made by my friends and me in my home page. There are 2 tables in the database related to this.

One of them is "friends" (list of members who are my friends can be obtained from this table). The other is "updates" (all the status updates are stored in this table).

The common field to both the tables is "memberID" (a unique number allotted to each member of the site).

So how do I obtain and print out the required information from these 2 tables?

I hope my question is clear. Do let me know if I need to clarify further.

By the way, I am developing the site using PHP (procedural programming only; no OOP), and I'm using MySQL database. Also, I would like the processing time and power required for running the script to be as low as possible, since I will be going for shared hosting.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code here and explain what didn't work and how did you attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: I hadn't. My first thought was to use 2 different queries - one for getting the friend list, the other for obtaining the updates using a while loop.
But then I realized that it wasn't helping me much. So I didn't proceed with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM updates INNER JOIN(friends) ON(updates.memberID = friends.memberID AND friends.userID = X) ORDER BY updates.date DESC LIMIT 0,N;
```

Where `friends.memberID` is the friend's memberID, `friend.userID` is the memberID of the person who to whom `friend.memberID` is a friend and `X` is the memberID of the logged in user.

P.S. I shivered when I read "procedural programming only". You're a braver soul than I.

Comment: Thank you.

P.S. Why do you say so?

Comment: Objects in general make things easier to manage.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not very comfortable with OOP. Trying to get more acquainted with Java, but haven't been too successful as of now.
The above mentioned question is related to a college project which I would like to complete as soon as possible. I will try to implement OOP in my next project.

Comment: Ah, understandable. Trying to learn OOP while working on a project with a tight deadline is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: I modified your answer a bit to allow posts by me to be visible too. The modified part now reads ((updates.memberID = friends.memberID OR updates.memberID = friends.userID) AND friends.userID = X).

Comment: @JDavidSmith Thing is that I have now run into a certain problem related to this. Suppose I need to extract both **table1.colA** and **table2.colA**, whose values are different. So how do I print them in PHP. If their values had been same, I may have pulled them by **$result['colA']**. Alternatively, if the fields had different names (_colA_ and _colB_ respectively, for instance), I would have used **$result['colA']** and **$result['colB']**. But that's not the case. So how do I print their values now? I tried using **$result['field1']['colA']**; but it threw an error.

So what do I do now?

Comment: SQL has the `SELECT colA AS colB` syntax just for situations like this. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html (will have to scroll down a bit, the mysql docs don't have good in-page bookmarking)

Comment: "It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed". Seems like my own query isn't working with AS because of that. My query, without using AS -

**$myQuery = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM statusUpdates INNER JOIN(friends) ON((statusUpdates.hostID = friends.contactID OR statusUpdates.hostID = friends.hostID) AND friends.hostID = 105086) ORDER BY statusUpdates.statusID DESC LIMIT 0,5") ;**

Comment: So how do I print hostID of statusUpdates.hostID (and not friends.hostID) from the above query?

Comment: Try this: `$result['statusUpdates.hostID']`. If that doesn't work, you may need to specify the columns you want manually rather than using `*`

Comment: I had already tried that one. It throws a warning: _Undefined index: statusUpdates.hostID_.
Also tried with `$result['statusUpdates']['hostID']`, but in vain.

By the way, I would just like to mention at this point that after this problem is solved, I would try to add (using `INNER JOIN`) another table **users** where _profile link_, _profile picture_ and other details are stored.

Comment: I changed the name of the fields in my tables. This solved the problem as of now, although I would have preferred getting a solution without editing my database.

Answer (score 1):

Your user id = YOU

so:

```
mysql_query("

select * from updates where memberID in (select friend_id from friends where  memberID  = 'YOU') order by date desc limit 0,N;

");
```

this result will give what you want.